# Matrix to transform coordinates between viewport and transformed rectangle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to write a matrix that transforms between the local coordinates of a transformed rectangle on the screen and the viewport coordinates.

As illustrated in the following graph:

- The red local (L) coordinates represent the rectangle, from (0, 0) to (1, 1)
- The orange global (G) coordinates represent the viewport, from (0, 0) to (1, 1)
- The rectangle is centered at its (0.5, 0.5) coordinates, and rotated around that pivot by theta  (orange)
- I'm trying to write a matrix that transforms the green local coordinates into the magenta global coordinates

[image: Graph]

So far, I have the following code, which works for translation and scaling, and seems to rotate in the right direction.

**But there seems to be some form of skewing when rotation is applied**:

```cs
public Matrix4x4 LocalToViewportMatrix
{
    get
    {
        Vector2 translation = viewportPosition;
        float rotation = this.rotation;
        Vector2 scale = viewportSize;
        Vector2 centering = -(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        
        Matrix4x4 T = Matrix4x4.Translate(translation.WithZ(0));
        Matrix4x4 R = Matrix4x4.Rotate(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotation));
        Matrix4x4 S = Matrix4x4.Scale(scale.WithZ(1));
        Matrix4x4 t = Matrix4x4.Translate(centering.WithZ(0));

        return T * R * S * t;
    }
}
```

- `viewportPosition` maps to the blue `G(x, y)` rectangle center on the graph
- `rotation` maps to the orange theta angle on the graph
- `viewportSize` maps to the relative size of the *unrotated* rectangle compared to the viewport; basically if you took `length(red axes) / length(blue axes)`

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with my order of operations, but I tried many things and can't figure it out.

Comment: This sounds almost like [`Camera.worldToCameraMatrix`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-worldToCameraMatrix.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by using absolute pixel coordinates for the viewport instead of a relative [0, 1] range. I'm not exactly sure how to explain it, but I think the fact that the coordinate system was not of the same length on both axes introduced the skewing.

```cs
public Matrix4x4 LocalToScreenMatrix
{
    get
    {
        var ScreenSize = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height);
        var screenPosition = viewportPosition * ScreenSize;
        var screenSize = viewportSize * ScreenSize;

        var translation = screenPosition;
        var rotation = this.rotation;
        var scale = screenSize;
        var centering = -new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);

        var T = Matrix4x4.Translate(translation.WithZ(0));
        var R = Matrix4x4.Rotate(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotation));
        var S = Matrix4x4.Scale(scale.WithZ(1));
        var t = Matrix4x4.Translate(centering.WithZ(0));

        return T * R * S * t;
    }
}
```